# Not able to access profile created with OpenID

Tags: support, login, accounts, openid

I had a profile, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300056/rta, which was created with OpenID.

Now it seems Stack Overflow is not allowing OpenID any more, so is there any way with that I can get access this profile?

Comment: I can still use OpenId, did you click the *more login options* link on the [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)? If yes, then explain what doesn't work. Any errors in your dev console of your browser? other errors?

Answer (score 2):

We support OpenID as a protocol still, but you signed up using myOpenID which [shut its servers down about 3.5 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac).

I'm ... not sure we have a good way to verify your ownership of the account at this point. But, [contact our support team](/contact) and we'll see what we can do.